# TWRP, Updater processes ended with ERROR: 7

Tags: factory-reset, twrp, lineageos, system-error

Whenever I try to flash Lineage OS with TWRP v 3.2.1-0, I'm getting

```
Updater processes ended with ERROR: 7
Error installing zip file '/sdcard/...n1awifi-signed.zip
```

When I check my `recovery.log`

```
Skipping Digest check: no Digest file found
I:Update binary zip
I:Zip does not contain SELinux file_contexts file in its root.
I:has_legacy_properties: Found legacy property match!
I:Legacy property environment initialized.
Target: samsung/lt03wifiue/lt03wifiue:5.1.1/LMY47X/P600UEUDOK1:user/release-keys
Target: samsung/lt03wifiue/lt03wifiue:5.1.1/LMY47X/P600UEUDOK1:user/release-keys
detected filesystem ext4 for /dev/block/platform/dw_mmc.0/by-name/SYSTEM
detected filesystem ext4 for /dev/block/platform/dw_mmc.0/by-name/SYSTEM
about to run program [/tmp/install/bin/backuptool.sh] with 2 args
Not backing up files from incompatible version: 14.1
run_program: child exited with status 127
about to run program [/tmp/install/bin/otasigcheck.sh] with 1 args
You have an installed system that isn't signed with this build's key, aborting...
run_program: child exited with status 124
script aborted: Can't install this package on top of incompatible data. Please try another package or run a factory reset
Can't install this package on top of incompatible data. Please try another package or run a factory reset
Updater process ended with ERROR: 7
```

How do I resolve this error I have validated that my TWRP and my rom (that I'm trying to flash) matches my architecture (per model number and the result of `/proc/cpuinfo`)

Comment: What is your TWRP version? I've heard that error 7 is mostly due to TWRP being out of date. Try updating it from https://twrp.me/

Comment: @SSS I'm on version 3.2.1-0 (latest version)

Comment: What's the full error? If I'm not mistaken there should be something more than just "Error 7".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2682905&page=85)

> The reason is clear: You haven't done a factory reset. If you're coming from another rom, you can make a Titanium Backup of your apps and restore it after installing cm11. [...] Either way, you need to do a factory reset/full wipe. You will lose your apps, data, pretty much everything. Make a backup first, do the wipe, then it will install.

Comment: If the solution has fixed your problem you can mark it as solved.

Comment: @SSS I always do, unfortunately this absurd network requires I wait 2 days. I think upvotes remove that timer though =)

Comment: Oh okay, never done it myself so I wouldn't know.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I guess the "absurdity" is to make sure one doesn't start answering and accepting their own answers just to rack reputation.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman you don't get reputation from accepting your own answers. It's apparently to give a fair chance for others to answer the question [(read here)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). Still a dumb thing though if you've fixed your own problem.

Comment: @EvanCarroll why not :P   I'll upvote because I've never seen this answer to the problem, I just assumed everyone did their resets properly

Comment: @SSS It makes sense, actually, as some answers might just be expressed in a better form, or lack info.

Comment: @SSS I just went back to factory because my partition table got borked. =(

Comment: Instead of "Error 7" why didn't they just say "format your phone first".  Those kind of people were responsible for y2k lol